# Finding a particular solution of an inhomogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can one find a particular solution of $$y'' = 120x^4 + 180 x?$$

I assumed $$Y_p= Ax^4+ Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E.$$

I am not able to find $D$ and $E$.

Comment: This is because they can assume any value: In the ODE, $y$ only occurs in $y''$, which doesn't see the $0$th and $1$st order terms of $Y_p$. In fact, because $y$ only occurs this way, we can solve for $y$ by integrating the r.h.s. twice, and this introduces arbitrary terms $dx + e$, where $d$ and $e$ are the constants of integration.

Comment: What did you get for the general solution of the homogeneous equation $y''=0$?

Comment: $y$ is a polynomial of degree $6$, since taking the second derivative decreases the degree by $2$, reaching $4$.

Comment: i got A=0 B=30 and C=0 so the answer will be Yp= 30x^3 + Dx + E

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest kind of ODEs where you simply need to integrate (twice) and then get:
$$
y_p=4x^6+30x^3.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''=120x^4+180x$$
$$y'=\int(120x^4+180x)dx+C_1=24x^5+90x^2+C_1$$
$$y=\int(24x^5+90x^2+C_1)dx+C_2=4x^6+30x^3+C_1x+C_2$$
This is the general solution of your differential equation; you can get a particular solution by specifying values for $C_1$ and $C_2$. For example, setting $C_1=C_2=0$, you get the particular solution
$$Y_p=4x^6+30x^3.$$